# On clicking search button display update button and hide save button

Tags: jsp, struts2

```
<s:if test='%{cust_id!=""}'>
<s:submit cssclass="pagebutton" action="Custmer_ entry" theme="simple" value="update" on click="validate"/>
```

on loading page,I want to hide update button.On clicking search button display update button and hide save button.

Comment: Where the first button?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I was wrong.
When you check

```
    <s:if test='%{cust_id!=""}'>
```

You need to check if it is null like

```
    <s:if test='%{cust_id!="" || cust_id!=null}'>
```

Please check it this way